# Where does `file://` reference in an electron server

Tags: node.js, file, path, electron, localhost

I wish to access the file system, but the `file://` prefix does not seem to correspond to the absolute path.

When trying to `fetch('file://<absolute path to file>')` 
e.g. Users/name/dir/file I seem to be unable to locate the file required.

Omitting the file part, fetch appends the relative path to the end of localhost, what does `file` reference if it's not the absolute path?

Comment: `file://` can be absolute or relative, in general. Node.js does itself not restrict access. Perhaps the (not shown) `file://..` usage is incorrect? Note that [the `//` are *part of the protocol, not path*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#How_many_slashes?).

Comment: Usage: `fetch('file://Users/myusername/project/file.h5', {mode: 'no-cors'})` the file exists under said absolute path. @user2864740

Comment: That's not an _absolute_ path; it's still relative. It is missing a '/'. See above link.

Comment: @user2864740 How would I set an absolute path in that case?  `fetch('/Users/myusername/project/file.h5', {mode: 'no-cors'}) ` just adds it to the end of the localhost ip.

Comment: See the link above: `'file:///Users/myusername/project/file.h5'`

Comment: @user2864740 Ah that makes sense now. I can mark it as correct if you post it as an answer.